# Android crop ImageView inside parent RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, image, scale, crop

I would like to know how can I crop a `ImageView` that have a scaled background image using a fixed width and height on it's `parent`.

Basically, I want an image to be scaled using `ImageView android:background` and then I want to crop the portion of the image that is outside the parent's bounds.

Until now, I have this code:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/time_foregrd"
    android:layout_width="57px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100px"
    android:layout_marginTop="285px"
    android:clipChildren="true"
   >
    <ImageView  android:layout_width="57px"
                android:layout_height="338px"
                android:minWidth="57px"
                android:minHeight="338px"
                android:background="@drawable/time_foreground"
                />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But it doesn't work... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I managed how to do that. Instead of using `RelativeLayout`, I used `FrameLayout` and it worked perfectly.

Here's the code:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/time_foregrd"
    android:layout_width="57px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100px"
    android:layout_marginTop="285px"
   >
    <ImageView  android:layout_width="57px"
                android:layout_height="338px"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/time_foreground"
                />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Is it not working when using `RelativeLayout`? Because I need more than one child inside this container.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the same thing in my RelativeLayout using

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

1- wrap that element  with  relativeLayout.

2- add this to your element :`android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

it will act just as ImageView's scaleType="centerCrop"

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250.0dp" >
        <TextureView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="451.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_YourElement"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" /> 

    </LinearLayout>
```

android:layout_gravity=
"center_vertical" ,
"center_horizontal",
"center", ...